# Index Out Of Bound Exception Invalid index 16, size is 15

Tags: java, for-loop, indexoutofboundsexception

I wrote some code to load a lot of pictures step by step into imageviews. But if i run the code i get Index Out of Bound Exception: Invalid index 16, size is 15

Here is my Code

```
int steps = 5;
int tmp = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < imageUrl.size(); j++) {
    if (imageUrl.size() < steps) {
        for (int i = 0; i < imageUrl.size(); i++) {
            buildPicture(imageUrl.get(tmp));
            imageUrl.remove(tmp);
            tmp++;
        }
    } else if (imageUrl.size() >= steps) {
        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
            buildPicture(imageUrl.get(tmp));
            imageUrl.remove(tmp);
            tmp++;
        }
    }
}
```

Please, can you help me fixed my code?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger?

Comment: It's not clear from this code what you expect the value of `tmp` to be - what are you trying to achieve with it? Have you considered what it will be at the start of the second iteration of the outer loop?

Comment: yes, as exaple, i tried with a imageUrl size of 24, the loop terminated after 12 runs.

Comment: I have an ArrayList of X items. What I want is too take 5 items and put them into the imageView. The loop should repeat until the ende of ArrayList. I think tmp is my index for the ArrayList.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do but notice `t` is  set to 0 only before the loop. Is that what you meant to do ?

Answer (score 0):

When size equals 15 the last element index is 14 because the index of first element is always 0.

Comment: and how can i fix it? and why the loop terminate after midway of the ArrayList. I tried with ArryList size of 24 and 19. The loop terminates after 12 and 10

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the for loop runs once less, because the array starts at 0 and not 1:
EDIT: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, I don't understand why are you using temp instead of the current [i] value of the loops. Try this though, if not, I'm not sure...

```
   int steps = 5;
for (int j = 0; j < (imageUrl.size() - 1); j++) {
    if (imageUrl.size() < steps) {
        for (int i = 0; i < (imageUrl.size() - 1); i++) {
            buildPicture(imageUrl.get(i));
            imageUrl.remove(i);
        }
    } else if (imageUrl.size() >= steps) {
        for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
            buildPicture(imageUrl.get(i));
            imageUrl.remove(i);
            i++;
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I tried it out but if i run the code, I get this: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 9, size is 9

Comment: Does it say the index of  'something' or size of 'something'?

Comment: No, sorry. This is the Log: 

Process: com.example.dudi.myidea, PID: 25617
                                                                         java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 11, size is 11
                                                                             at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
                                                                             at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
                                                                             at

Answer (score 0):

Say imageUrl has a size of 24 like in your comment above. You're getting an out of bounds exception because tmp eventually becomes a value that's bigger than 24, and when you try to invoke `imageUrl.get(tmp)`, you're attempting to get an element that doesn't exist and hence the exception is thrown.

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here, but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

A short demonstration about reason behind the request to post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). An MCVE like:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    //use a variable instead of imageUrl.size()
    int imageUrlsize = 15;
    int steps = 5;
    int tmp = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < imageUrlsize; j++) {
        if (imageUrlsize < steps) {
            for (int i = 0; i < imageUrlsize; i++) {
                System.out.println("imageUrlsize < steps " + tmp);
                tmp++;
            }
        } else if (imageUrlsize >= steps) {
            for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++) {
                System.out.println("imageUrlsize >= steps "+ tmp);
                tmp++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Makes it very clear that for `imageUrl` of size 15 `tmp` grows to 74.